# Can we have notification for upvotes on comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, comment-votes

You can only upvote comments. First off, why can you **only** upvote comments. Wouldn't it make sense to be able to downvote them as well? Also, is there a way to get notification when your own comment has received an upvote?

Comment: I would think that people who get a lot of comment upvotes would absolutely hate this noise. _ping_ _ping_ _ping_

Comment: @bluefeet ping ping ping pingety ping

Comment: Come on guys, this is an honest question. What is wrong here?

Comment: @RPM, downvotes on Meta mean disagreement. Some of us disagree with your proposal. No offense meant. Ping ping aaaaaaarrgh

Comment: Why not provide a settings so people has option to decide and turn on/off this notification. I personally glad like to know if someone agree my comment by upvote.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's called [Alarm Fatigue](http://www.npr.org/blogs/health/2014/01/24/265702152/silencing-many-hospital-alarms-leads-to-better-health-care).

In short, notifications have to be judicious.  Otherwise, they are summarily ignored.

Comment: The upvote was from me.

Answer (score 1):

What benefit would this offer you the writer of said comment?

You can only delete old comments, you can't edit them and the up-vote confers no reputation. So what does knowing that 6 people "like" your comment actually achieve?

Comment: Higher quality comments?

Comment: @RPM - surely then you'd want to know the ones that were flagged as they're the bad ones.

Comment: Sure, I'll take that feature too.

Comment: Why stop there?  I'd like to be notified when I get upvotes and downvotes on questions too.  While we're at it, I'd like a notification when ChrisF looks at one of my posts.  Or every time a Redditor looks at one of my posts.  Pingety ping.

Comment: @RPM - I wasn't being serious with that suggestion.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I really don't understand the need for the sarcastic comments. This would perhaps be a logical feature that I believe would make sense. It doesn't seem unusual to me.

Comment: Fine, I'll write a serious answer.